# Ignoring case in strings with unitils ReflectionComparator

Tags: java, unitils, ignore-case

I'm using [unitils](http://www.unitils.org/) tool for deep objects comparing, via `ReflectionComparator`:

```
ReflectionComparatorMode[] modes = {ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS};
ReflectionComparator comparator = ReflectionComparatorFactory.createRefectionComparator(modes);
Difference difference = comparator.getDifference(oldObject, newObject);
```

It turns out that this `ReflectionComparator` doesn't ignore case in `String` fields values. And there isn't sprecial mode for this purpose in `ReflectionComparatorMode` enum:

```
public enum ReflectionComparatorMode {
    IGNORE_DEFAULTS,
    LENIENT_DATES,
    LENIENT_ORDER
}
```

Any ideas, how it could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigation of how `ReflectionComparator` works gave me this workable solution. Saying in brief, we have to add another one special `Comparator` object for dealing with `String` objects in comparators chain.

Also we have to do some *bedlam* with extracting one needed `protected` static method from `ReflectionComparatorFactory` in order to reduce code doubling.

```
ReflectionComparatorMode[] modes = {ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS};

List<org.unitils.reflectionassert.comparator.Comparator> comparators = new ArrayList<>();
    comparators.add(new Comparator() {
         @Override
         public boolean canCompare(Object left, Object right) {
               return left instanceof String && right instanceof String;
         }

         @Override
         public Difference compare(Object left, Object right, boolean onlyFirstDifference, ReflectionComparator reflectionComparator) {
               return  ((String) left).equalsIgnoreCase((String) right) ? null : new Difference("Non equal values: ", left, right);
         }
});

comparators.addAll(
    new ReflectionComparatorFactory() {
        public List<Comparator> getComparatorChainNonStatic(Set<ReflectionComparatorMode> modes) {
               return getComparatorChain(modes);
        }
    }.getComparatorChainNonStatic(asSet(modes)));

ReflectionComparator comparator = new ReflectionComparator(comparators);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReflectionComparatorMode` has no mode to mimic `ignore_case` behavior.
You do not specify the types of `oldObject` and `newObject` but I guess you can either '*normalize*' them before passing them to `ReflectionComparator` (convert all `String` fields to either upper or lower case) or implement your own Java Comparator based on the specific type of `oldObject` and `newObject`.

Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).

Comment: Thanks, but I can not. I'm dealing with tons of different classes and if I could normalize them all, it would be much simpler do compare manually without any `unitils` tool.

Comment: Feel your pain. Maybe you can use ReflectionUtils http://unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/util/ReflectionUtils.html to massage both objects before passing them to the ReflectionComparator?

Comment: Thanks again for you idea, but I found really workable universal solution. If you are interesting, look at my answer

Comment: @avaid I mean "universal" in sense of avoiding manually coding normalization for all objects